# NoSuchElementException when trying to locate an input field using xpath in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to locate an input element on a page and fill it in with a string. I have tried probably 6 plus ways of achieving this but I keep getting the NoSuchElement error. The page I am working with requires authentication and the page is huge so I will not able to provide a link or full code but below is what I can provide:

I used xPath Helper to find the details for the input field in question:

```
/html[@class='js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths gr__login2_navient_com Chrome Chrome77']/body/form[@id='command']/div[@class='l-page page-template3']/div[@class='l-main']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='l-content']/div[@class='row'][2]/div[@class='col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-12']/div[@class='step row'][1]/div[@class='form-item form-item-3 social-date with-i-btn']/input[@id='lblSSN1']
```

Below is the code for the input field itself:

```
<input type="tel" id="lblSSN1" name="tSSN1" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" aria-labelledby="fieldLevelError_SSN SSN" onkeyup="AutoTabMasking(document.LoginForm.tSSN1,document.LoginForm.tSSN2,3,event,document.LoginForm.SSN1,document.LoginForm.dSSN1)" onblur="AutoMasking(document.LoginForm.tSSN1,3,document.LoginForm.SSN1);" onclick="javascript: cleanAccError(); return calm2CheckInput('SSN', 'SSN1');" onfocus="javascript: cleanAccError(); return calm2CheckInput('SSN', 'SSN1');" style="background-color: white;" class="xh-highlight">
```

As you can see the input field has **id('lblSSN1')**, **name('tSSN1')** and **type('tel')** and I have tried many combinations of this but still no luck.

Below are just some of the options I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='tSSN1'][@id='lblSSN1']").send_keys('000')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lblSSN1']").send_keys('000')    
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='command']/input[12]").send_keys('000')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='lblSSN1']").send_keys('000')
driver.find_element_by_name('tSSN1').send_keys('000')
driver.find_element_by_id('lblSSN1').send_keys('000')
```

I am using the Firefox driver and Python 3.

Comment: did you check for presence of any iframes?

Comment: Yes. No iFrames on this page. There was an iFrames on the login page before this page and took a while to get it working so that was the first thing I checked on this page.

Comment: try adding wait times to these elements. the xpaths seems to be correct.

Comment: Induce some WebDriverWait and check if it works.

Comment: Wow!!! How did I neglect the wait time? Been banging my head against my desk for like an hour. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wait for the element:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(driver.visibility_of_element_located((By. ID, "lblSSN1")))

driver.find_element_by_id("lblSSN1")
```